# Smart way to format tables on stdout in C

Tags: c, format, stdout, tabular

I am trying to write table to stdout with numerical data. I would like to format so that numbers are aligned like:

```
1234     23
 312   2314
  12    123
```

I know that max length of the number is 6 chars, is there a smart way to know how many spaces needs to be output before number so it looks exactly like this?

Comment: Look at `std::setw` and `std::setfill` in `<iomanip>`.

Comment: is there a way without using <iomanip>? I know it sounds strange but I would like to make my code as portable as possible

Comment: @Blackie123 : `iomanip` is a header that comes with the C++ standard library -- you can't find anything _more_ portable...

Comment: All right, you persuaded me :) thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`printf` may be the quickest solution:

```
#include <cstdio>

int a[] = { 22, 52352, 532 };

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    std::printf("%6i %6i\n", a[i], a[i]);
}
```

Prints:

```
    22     22
 52352  52352
   532    532
```

Something similar can be achieved with an arduous and verbose sequence of iostream commands; someone else will surely post such an answer should you prefer the "pure C++" taste of that.

---

*Update:* Actually, the iostreams version isn't that much more terrible. (As long as you don't want scientific float formatting or hex output, that is.) Here it goes:

```
#include <iostreams>
#include <iomanip>

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(6) << a[i] << " " << std::setw(6) << a[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't care about "pure C++" so much, but the type safety sure is nice... ;-]

Comment: More people are familiar with `%d` than with `%i`.

Comment: what do you mean by type safety? this way looks much better than using additional libraries

Comment: @Blackie123: `printf` isn't type-safe; it is easy to cause UB without any diagnostics. Streaming to `std::cout` is safer, since you will get a compiler error if you use it wrong. Also, things like `uint32_t` or `std::size_t` are a pain to print with `printf`. `printf` is really only good for the primitive ur-types. It's my guilty pleasure and I often use it to hexdump things, but one shouldn't really advise it...

Comment: @Blackie123 : `printf` is part of the C runtime; `std::cout` is part of the C++ runtime. In practice, you need both anyway, so there are no "additional libraries".

Comment: @moshbear: I can never think of what `%d` would stand for (%i int, %u unsigned, %li and %lu as expected. `%d`?? WTF? double? Decimal? C++ doesn't even have decimals...)

Comment: I just need to write bunch of integers. I am not sure how could something like that cause safety issues

Comment: @sehe: Hence you will be grateful that I eschewed the use of `%d` altogether with concern for the elderly :-) Blackie: You can only safely use `printf` with `int`, `long int`, `long long int` etc. If you have `uint64_t` or `size_t`, you need some convoluted macro.

Comment: you don't strictly need a convoluted macro. Both `uint64_t` and `size_t` can be cast to `unsigned long long` and output with printf portably.

Comment: @kaizer.se : With what format specifier? Note that they're different between VC++ and GCC, so it's not possible _portably_ without some preprocessor intervention.

Comment: @Blackie123 Varargs performs type erasure. That can lead to nasty yet subtle bugs because printf uses the type field to determine what the next arg is, so that it can call the correct `va_xxx`.

Comment: @kaizer.se: Ah, right, if you cast it in the printf call... I hadn't thought of that. Though now it's approaching levels of verbosity that compete with that of iostreams :-)

Comment: @moshbear: That's not really what "type erasure" normally means... do note though that variadic arguments incur "standard promotions", which are often a stumbling point.

Comment: I added the iostreams/iomanip version for good measure. It isn't actually too bad.

Comment: Regarding your edit: why is hex output painful with iostreams? It's a single manipulator call... +1 for finally adding the iostreams code though. :-]

Comment: all right I included <iomanip>... Case closed! Thank you guys for your quick response!

Comment: @ildjarn: Until you then want to print decimals elsewhere again... don't get me started! :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB : [Boost.IoStateSavers](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) to the rescue! ;-D

Comment: @ildjarn: or just do a `std::ostream format_cout(std::cout.rdbuf());` and set the flags on the separate stream to avoid the mess

Comment: or use ostringstream for the formatting, and then just pass the string to cout

Answer (score 4):

For c, use "%6d" to specify printing, i.e.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < ROWS(a); ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < COLS(a); ++j) 
        printf("%6d ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

For c++,

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < ROWS(a); ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < COLS(a); ++j) 
         std::cout  << a[i][j] << ' ';  
    std::cout << std::setw(6) << std::endl;
}
```

Don't forget to `#include <iomanip>`.

Use of cout is strongly recommended over printf for type safety reasons.
If I remember correctly, Boost has a type-safe replacement for printf, so you can use
that instead of you require the format-string, args form.

Comment: doesn't `setw` need to be called before *every* operation?

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = 
        { { 1,2,3 },
          { 4,5,6 },
          { 7,8,9 },
          { 10,11,12 },
          { 13,14,15 }, };

    std::cout << karma::format(
             *karma::right_align(7, ' ') [ karma::int_ ] % '\n', a) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
  1      2      3
  4      5      6
  7      8      9
 10     11     12
 13     14     15
```