# How do I align my last column according the the column using Printf

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I have a problem of trying to align the last column of numbers according to the third column header using C programming.I would like to set the width of a column to 15 characters. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
printf("%-15s ", "Fahrenheit     Celsius        Kelvin         \n");
printf("---------------------------------------------\n");    
printf("%-15d""%.2f           %-.2f           \n", fahrenheit, celsius, kelvin);
```

My output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart way to format tables on stdout in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548909/smart-way-to-format-tables-on-stdout-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use a *width* with the *print specifier*.

Also consider `"-"` *flag* with the print specifier to left justify output.

```
  int fahrenheit = 0;
  double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / (180 / 100.0);
  double kelvin = celsius + 273.15;

  int width_f = 15;  // Adjust widths as desired
  int width_c = 12;
  int width_k = 12;
  int line_n = width_f + 1 + width_c + 1 + width_k;
  char line[line_n + 1]; // VLA
  memset(line, '-', line_n);
  line[line_n] = '\0';

  printf("%*s %*s %*s\n", //
      width_f, "Fahrenheit", width_c, "Celsius", width_k, "Kelvin");
  printf("%s\n", line);
  printf("%*d %*.2f %*.2f\n", //
      width_f, fahrenheit, width_c, celsius, width_k, kelvin);
```

Output

```
     Fahrenheit      Celsius       Kelvin
-----------------------------------------
              0       -17.78       255.37
```